# MongoDB - the update operation document must contain atomic operators

Tags: mongodb

I am attempting to do an updateMany operation on a collection, but I'm running into issues.

I'm not sure what else to change to make this work.

```
db.getCollection("Sales").updateMany({"LocationId": {$regex : /^0/}},
[{ 
    $set: { 
        LocationId: {  
            $substr: ["$LocationId", 1, -1] 
            } 
        }
    },
    { upsert: true }    
]);
```

Comment: Your query works, except for the `upsert`. It is not a pipeline stage and should be moved outside the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with the following:

```
db.getCollection("Sales").update(
     {LocationId: { $regex : /^0/}},
     [{$set:{
        LocationId:{
             $substrBytes:[
                           "$LocationId",
                           1,
                           { $subtract: [ { $strLenBytes: "$LocationId" }, 1 ] }
             ]
        }
     }}],
     {multi:true}
```

)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).